# How to fix errors in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC unit test with XUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-6.0, xunit.net, c#-6.0

I am testing a simple ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app using XUnit. The web app project was created in Visual Studio 2022. I did add an area named `Admin` with structure setup by scaffolding.

The XUnit test project was setup to test loading the `Index` page.

Here is the test project code:

```
using Xunit;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MultiAreasTests
{
    public class MainSiteTests
    {
        private readonly TestServer _server;
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public MainSiteTests()
        {
            var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Program>(); // Provide the Startup class of your application
            _server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
            _client = _server.CreateClient();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void LoadIndexPageTest()
        {
            //Arrange
            string url = "https://localhost:7229/home/index";

            //Act
            var response = _client.GetAsync(url);
            int statusCode = (int)response.Status;
            Debug.WriteLine($"http response code: {statusCode}");

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(200, statusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to specify the `StartUp` class in unit test, I used the regular `status void main(....)` in `Program.cs`.

The PROGRAM.CS code:

```
using MultiAreas.Models;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IModymixDBContext, ModymixDBContext>();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
          name: "areas",
          pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=AMHome}/{action=AMIndex}/{id?}"
        );

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

When execute the test method, `LoadIndexPageTest`, the exception occurred on line 26:

```
_server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
```

The error message was:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Program' type.

It looks like that the problem is in `Program.cs` program. But, I am not sure how to fix it.  Any suggestions and assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the latest offical doc, we could use the default WebApplicationFactory to implement this requirement.

**Step 1.** Add Project Reference like below

[image]

**Step 2** My Test Code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace _76348888_test
{
    public class UnitTest1 : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<_76348888.Program>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<_76348888.Program> _factory;
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public UnitTest1(WebApplicationFactory<_76348888.Program> factory)
        {
            //var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<_76348888.Program>(); // Provide the Startup class of your application
            //_server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);

            _factory = factory;
            _client = _factory.CreateClient();
        }


        [Fact]
        public async void Test1()
        {
            //Arrange
            string url = "https://localhost:7239/home/index";

            //Act
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
            int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
            Debug.WriteLine($"http response code: {statusCode}");

            //Assert
            Assert.Equal(200, statusCode);
        }

    }
}
```

**Step 3** My Test Result

[image]

**The Reason for the error message**

There is no `Startup.cs` file inside the .net6 asp.net core mvc project when you using `UseStartup` method.

Comment: Followed your instructions and still running into a problem.  In test class, it doesn't recoganize the my "MultiAreas.Program" class.  I checked test project reference, it correctly set to the web project "MultiAreas".  The program.cs file is using the old style with "public class Program".  I tried to add "using MultiAreas" statement in test project. It does not work.  I checked test project file and found following: <ProjectReference Include="..\MultiAreas\MultiAreas.csproj" />.  Is the "..\" part in this setting caused the problem?

Comment: @bedrock Please provide or share a minimal project that reproduces the issue so I can help you see it. And please don't forget to hide the sensitive information.